# Losing session with Session Stickiness in Elastic Load Balancing AWS

Tags: session, amazon-web-services

Actually i'm new in aws , but the ZF2 project i work on has been merged into AWS so they used two servers and i'm facing the problem of losing sessions , where the problem comes ? and is that can be related to the config ?
we use `Session Stickiness`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you configure your ELB, you have 3 options for session affinity, none of them named "Session Stickiness".  You can have no session stickiness, you can have a cookie generated by the ELB, or you can generate a cookie in your application.  You also need to configure it on each port the ELB tier is listening on - so if you have an application that uses 80 and 443 then you'd need to enable it on both ports.

I would recommend using ELB generated cookies if you're not sure what's needed.

Comment: Ok , ihave one question plz , how to know if my application has its own session cookie ? thanks